# Solve: $\bigg(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\bigg)^5=2$

Tags: complex-numbers

> $$\bigg(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\bigg)^5=2$$

$$\bigg(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\cdot\frac{z-1}{z-1}\bigg)^5=2$$

$$\bigg(\frac{(z-1)^2}{|z|^2}\bigg)^5=2$$

$$\bigg(\frac{z-1}{|z|}\bigg)^{10}=2$$

How should I continue?

Comment: I don't think you got the conjugate step quite right there.

Comment: $(z+1)(z-1) \ne |z|^2$, so you shouldn't continue this particular calculation.

Comment: damnit mathreader, you got there a few seconds before me

Comment: @mdave16 Some other time it will be the other way around ;)

Comment: does anyone know how to undo edits, i think this will be my second rejection and i want to keep the rate down

Comment: I don't know. I almost never undo or remove anything. I think most people don't care too much as long as you write somewhere that it was a mistake.

Comment: Hint: it's easy to solve for $z$ in $(z-1)/(z+1) = a$, provided $a\ne !$.

Comment: @ErickWong like Dr. Sonnhard Graubner approach?

Comment: @gbox No, that approach looks ridiculously complex.  Just try solving it for real $z$ and $a$ first.  The exact same approach works for complex $z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** Write
$$
\frac{z+1}{z-1}=w:=re^{i\theta}
$$
solve $w^5=2$ and finally find $z$.

Comment: just to be sure $r=\sqrt{2^2}=2$?

Comment: Your fraction is upside down.

Answer (score 0):

i have $$\left(\frac{a-1+bi}{a+1+bi}\right)^5 =2$$ and from here we get
$$(a^2+b^2-1+2bi)^5=2((a+1)^2+b^2)^5$$

Comment: Can you please explain how did you get to $(a^2+b^2+2bi)$ and $((a+1)^2+b^2)$?

Comment: by multiplying numerator and denominator by $$a+1-bi$$

Comment: And now I can compare real and imaginary parts?

Comment: this would i do

Comment: Sorry for the questions I am really trying to learn, but how can I compare with the 22, if it was just $(a^2+b^2-1+2bi)^5=((a+1)^2+b^2)^5$ so we have $a^2+b^2-1=(a+1)^2+b^2$ for the real part and $2bi=0$ for the imaginary one

Comment: write the right side in the form $$(\sqrt[5]{32}(a+1)^2+\sqrt[5]{32}b^2)^5$$